# Интеграция Mailchimp в Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress

Ребят, кто разбирается в PHP, помогите, пожалуйста.

Нужно прикрутить Mailchimp к ContactForm7, нашел метод, но он у меня не работает. Есть предположение, что это из-за того, что у Mailchimp обновился API.

В методе используется MCAPI v1.3.1, а на сайте мэйлчимпа доступна версия MCAPI v1.3.2 ([ссылка на файл](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/mailchimp-api-class.zip)).

Вот код:

```
function wpcf7_send_to_mailchimp($cfdata) {

$formtitle = $cfdata->title;
$formdata = $cfdata->posted_data;
$send_this_email = $formdata['your-email'];
$mergeVars = array(
'FNAME'=>$formdata['your-first-name'],
'LNAME'=>$formdata['your-last-name'],
'GROUPINGS'=>array( array('name'=>'Form Used', 'groups'=>$formtitle),
));

// MCAPI.class.php needs to be in theme folder
require_once('MCAPI.class.php');

// grab an API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
$api = new MCAPI('--------API KEY---------');

// grab your List's Unique Id by going to http://admin.mailchimp.com/lists/
// Click the "settings" link for the list - the Unique Id is at the bottom of that page.
$list_id = "---------Unique ID---------";

// Send the form content to MailChimp List without double opt-in
$retval = $api->listSubscribe($list_id, $send_this_email, $mergeVars, 'html', false);

}
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'wpcf7_send_to_mailchimp', 1);
```

Всё делается на wordpress. Код вставляю в functions темы, а файл MCAPI v1.3.2 лежит в папке темы, там же, где и файл functions.php.